# when the user uses tab key instead of mouse to enter the mobile number before entering the number it say mobile already exists javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Php:

```
require_once('master_assets/conn/connectvars.php');
if (isset($_GET['phone'])) {
  $phone = $_GET['phone'];

  $comp   = "SELECT phone FROM users WHERE phone ='$phone' ";
  $query  = mysqli_query($connection, $comp);
  $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);


  if ($result > 0) {

      echo "<p style='color: red;padding: 0px;font-size: 13px;    margin: 7px;'> Mobile Already Exist! </p>";

  } else {

      echo "";
  }
  exit();

}
if (isset($_GET['email'])) {

  $email = $_GET['email'];

  $comp2  = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email' ";
  $query  = mysqli_query($connection, $comp2);
  $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

  if ($result > 0) {
    echo "<p style='color: red;padding: 0px;font-size: 13px;    margin: 7px;'> EmailID Already Exist! </p>";
  } else {
    echo "";
  }
  exit();
}
```

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#email_check, #mobile_check').change(function(){
    if((parseInt($('#phone_count').val()) != 0 ) || (parseInt($('#email_count').val()) != 0) ){
      button1.style.display = "none";
      button2.style.display = "inline-block";
    }else{
      button1.style.display = "inline-block";
      button2.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});

function phones(){
  var phone=document.getElementById('mobile_check').value;
  //var email=document.getElementById('phone_count').value;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      http1=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      http1=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    http1.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (http1.readyState==4 )
      {
        var respo=http1.responseText;  
        if($.trim(respo)!='')
        {
          button1.style.display = "none";
          button2.style.display = "inline-block";
        }
        else
        {
          button1.style.display = "inline-block";
          button2.style.display = "none";
        }

        if($.trim(respo)!=''){
          val = 1;
        }else{
          val = 0;
        }

        document.getElementById('phone_count').value = val ;
        document.getElementById('mobile_errors').innerHTML=respo;                     
      }           
    }           
    http1.open("GET","../mobile_email_validation.php?phone=" + phone , true);  
    http1.send(null);
  }

  function emails()
  {        
    var val = "";
    var email = document.getElementById('email_check').value;
    //var email=document.getElementById('email_count').value;
    //alert(email);

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      http1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      http1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    http1.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (http1.readyState == 4) {
        var respo2 = http1.responseText;
        if ($.trim(respo2) != '') {

          button1.style.display = "none";
          button2.style.display = "inline-block";
        } else {
          button1.style.display = "inline-block";
          button2.style.display = "none";
        }

        if ($.trim(respo2) != '') {
          val = 1;
        } else {
          val = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('email_count').value = val;
        document.getElementById('email_errors').innerHTML = respo2;
      }
    }
  http1.open("GET", "../mobile_email_validation.php?email=" + email, true);
  http1.send(null);

  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="mobile_check">Phone *</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" id="mobile_check" onkeyup="phones()" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please type your mobile no" minlength="10" maxlength="10" >

      <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
        <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
      </span>
      <span  id="mobile_errors"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email_check">Email Id *</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" onkeyup="emails()" placeholder="Email" id="email_check" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please type your email">
      <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
        <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <span id="email_errors"></span>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id = "phone_count" value='0'>
  <input type="hidden" id = "email_count" value='0'>
</div>
```

when the user uses tab key instead of mouse to enter the mobile number before entering the number  it say mobile already exists javascript 
[image: i have added the error page also]

if say  some user does not want to use mouse and want to use tab key and enter the value in the fields. if i m using tab key it show mobile already exists beore entering the number

Comment: You should only post the relevant code here, but it sounds like you are listing to the wrong event. Perhaps you want the `blur` or `focusout` event?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems the event that trigger the phone() function: `keyup`.

`Keyup` is fired each time a user release a keyboard button that he has before pressed. In your case if an user navigate with TAB along your form, the TAB button is released when the focus is already in the `phone <input/>` and it trigger the event keyup before a user can write.

I suggest you to change your trigger event to on of these events:

```
onfoucusout
onchange
onblur
```

An alternative without change the event is to change your `phone()` function to block the validation brefore the user has write at last 3 numbers:

```
var phone=document.getElementById('mobile_check').value;
if(phone.length < 3) return true;
```

Now the TAB keyup has no effect (the validation isn't triggered if a user not writes 3 numbers at last)